# Can we merge Hybrid app with Native iOS App?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cordova

I have one Hybrid app(build on Phonegap) and one iOS App. The requirement is to merge both app into single app. some functionality drive from native and some through hybrid, is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. You can embed the phonegap webview in any native app, but as you already have the phonegap app created I recommend you to add the iOS app inside the phonegap app as if you do so, you don't have to manually add and configure phonegap in your native app.

You'll need a native tabbar controller or something like that to switch between the native view/viewcontroller and the phonegap view/viewcontroller

Here you can find the information about [phonegap as a component (embeding phonegap webview, also called cleaver)](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.4.0/guide_platforms_ios_webview.md.html#iOS%20WebViews), but I couldn't make it work to add phonegap plugins since phonegap 3.0, that's why I recommended you to start from the phonegap app instead embedding the phonegap webview in your native app

Comment: Could you please share with me any sample code.I trying but not able to find any way.

Comment: It's impossible to tell you without knowing your projects... Your phonegap app should have a MainViewController that it's loaded on the AppDelegate, you have to change the AppDelegate to load the native viewcontrollers too. You have to copy all your files from the native app to the phonegap app

Comment: Add AssetsLibrary.framework as it was not mentioned in http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.4.0/guide_platforms_ios_webview.md.html#iOS%20WebViews otherwise you would get error.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**, you can add the cocoa native app as plugin in PhoneGap and then configure it with config file.